# Characters are not showing on input text during keypress event - knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I want to restrict alphabet characters on my input so I made a function and bind it to input using `data-bind` on html, here it is

```
<input type="text" data-bind="valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { keypress: function(data, event) { restrictAlphabetCharacter(event); } }" placeholder="Year" maxlength="4">
```

And this is my function

```
restrictAlphabetCharacter(e) {
        var keyCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        if ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

What could be the reason why characters are not showing inside the textbox. Thank in advance.

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve your issue? if so, please mark my answer as accepted by ticking the V symbol to its left. If not, let me know and I'll try to further help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code allows characters with `keyCode` value of 48 to 57, which are digits only (i.e., 0 to 9). If you'd like to allow Alphabet letters only, restrict `keyCode` to 65 to 90 for uppercase letters and 97 to 122 for lowercase letters:

```js
function restrictAlphabetCharacter(data, e) {
    var keyCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if ((keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) ||
        (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122)) {
        return true;
    }
}
ko.applyBindings();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { keypress: restrictAlphabetCharacter }" placeholder="Year" maxlength="4">
```